# "Override" the FontSize property on a XAML UserControl

Tags: .net, xaml, user-controls, windows-phone-8.1

I have a UserControl for a Windows Phone 8.1 project that contains a TextBlock control. I would like to use the FontSize property which the UserControl inherits from the Control class. But I can't override the FontSize property and there doesn't seem to be a FontChanged event that I can subscribe to.

Ultimately, I would like to be able to set the FontSize attribute in the XAML of the page that contains my user control and have it migrate to the contained TextBlock's FontSize attribute/property.

Just not seeing how to do that.

First UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="KeyPadButton">
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Background="Gray" >
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="5" Padding="3"  >
            <TextBlock x:Name="Button" Text="9" FontSize="2"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Second UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="KeyPad">
    <Grid>
        <local:KeyPadButton Text="0" FontSize="22"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Containing Page:

```
<Page>
    <StackPanel>
        <local:KeyPad x:Name="KeyPad" FontSize="55"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

How can I set the FontSize of the KeyPad control in the Page and have it migrate down to the KeyPadButton control in the KeyPad?

Comment: Could you share your XAML containing the UserControl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmmm, turns out the mechanism is already there. I merely need to remove the FontSize attributes from the two UserControls and then the value of the FontSize attribute of the KeyPad control in the containing page is used by the KeyPad and KeyPadButton and then passed to the textblock in the KeyPadButton control.

(never mind.)

Answer (score 0):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TextBlock2}" BasedOn="{StaticResource styleMyTextBlock}" >
   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22" />
</Style>
```

the XAML works **WITHOUT** having to explicitly associate the "Style" to be used. It finds it based on the class association directly.

```
<src:TextBlock2 Content="Now Works as expected"/>
```

dont use `x:key` because if you have the `x:key`, its not implied by the class instance, but not having it, the direct class DOES find it automatically.

A style can be defined more than once to the same TARGET TYPE... However, one can have an `x:key` reference, and another a `BasedOn` reference. This APPEARS to be like **overloading a function** with same number, but different data type parameters.

Any direct class instances of the "TargetType" were NOT automatically linked up to the proper style, almost like the style declaration with the "x:key" REQUIRES any instances of a class to explicitly add the style context within the xaml of the control. So now, how to have it BOTH ways. I created a SECOND style with the TargetType as the baseclass, but BasedOn pointing to the x:key referenced one. This way, I get the default customization of the style, yet can STILL assign it to the baseclass and the derived class as well, so all 3 versions of a control can be automatically synchronized with the corresponding Style without EXPLICIT referencing.

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="wpfBaseTextBlock">
   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource wpfBaseTextBlock}" />

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TextBlock2}" BasedOn="{StaticResource wpfBaseTextBlock}">
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
</Style>
```

we can have all 3 "classes" used with or without explicit style association.